# Drive API filter file list by content size

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to get files with bigger than 5MB and smaller than 15MB (5MB & 15MB are just example) I want to know the structure of query in file.list()

```
results = service.files().list(q="size > '5MB' AND size < '10MB'", pageSize=10,
          fields="nextPageToken, files(*)").execute()
```

Comment: Here are the query terms: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms - there is no option to add query by size. You can get the whole list and filter it by the file size by your own code.

Comment: In which language are you trying to do this. In the following link you can check samples of the list operation in different languages: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk